# How to convert a timezone to its NI Real Time Controller notation in Java?

Tags: java, timezone

This question was misleading and unanswerable as originally written, because it turns out the real timezone format was not System V, but a slightly different one used by National Instruments. I was reverse engineering the protocol and I should not have been so sure I knew what I was talking about.

**Original Question:**

I am working with a network protocol that sends timezone information in System V notation (ie. EST5EDT or MST7MDT), and I need to convert the current timezone into this format using Java. Is there good or fairly good way to do this?

Comment: Is the target timezone format even unambiguous?

Comment: No, none with java that is even a fairly good way.

Comment: Some of them are supported aliases to tzdb zones, so a few may work out of the box.  But in general, the format is quite limited so they don't align well to most environments.  See the section on POSIX time zones in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 0):

The real answer (to the modified question) was found [here](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/CD3E1F89F47CCF2486257A76005B60C1) where there is a table showing UTC offsets and their associated names for National Instruments Real Time Controllers. This can be used as an okay way/kind of bad to convert timezones. Sorry for the bad question.